# From conditional to unconditional expectation

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

Consider a random variable $Y$ and a random variable $G$. $G$ can only take value $1$ or $0$.

Is it true that
$$
E(Y|G=0)\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow E((1-G)Y)
\geq 0 \quad ?$$

My thought is yes and below I report the proof (I imagine that $Y$ is discrete for simplicity). Is it correct? What is really that I'm leveraging on for this result?

$$
E(Y|G=0)=\sum_{y} y Pr(Y=y|G=0)\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{y} y Pr(Y=y|G=0)Pr(G=0)\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{y} y Pr(Y=y,G=0)\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow E((1-G)Y)\geq 0
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove this proposition by [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} (1-G)Y &= \mathbb{E}_G \mathbb{E}_Y( (1-G)Y | G)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(G=1) \mathbb{E}_Y(0*Y|G=1) + \mathbb{P}(G=0)\mathbb{E}_Y(1*Y| G=0)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(G=0) \mathbb{E}_Y(Y|G=0).
\end{align}
It is clear that your proposition is true. The key to proving this proposition is to use the $1-G$ as an indicator function.

Comment: Thank you @HJ Liang. Your answer is very nice. But I think P(G=1)EY(0∗Y|G=1) can not be written as 0 without any information about Y. There will be a problem if Y does not have finite marginal expectations i.e. if Y can be infinite with some probability.

Comment: Hello @MdAshiqurRahman, You don't have to consider Y since 0*Y = 0 a.s.

Comment: isn't 0*infinity is indeterminate? Here is a related post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45327/why-is-infty0-indeterminate#:~:text=In%20particular%2C%20infinity%20is%20the,which%20is%20an%20indeterminate%20form.

Comment: This is a good question! It seems that we only care about almost surely finite random variables in probability theory. I'm not sure in which book I have read this statement, and it may be an advanced probability textbook written by Kai Lai Chung or someone else.